# How to define which class with same name to use in Wildfly jboss

Tags: java, maven, jboss, pom.xml, wildfly-10

I worked for some months with a project ran on tomcat.

Then i used to create class with same name in order to hide the ones present in jar (downloaded by maven).
I can understand this is not the cleanest thing at all, but its very powerfull and usefull.

Now i would like to do the same with this new project in wildfly 10 but there is no way to do that.

My project contains different module but i dont see any hierarchy on the pom

**How i can understand if the problem is linked to project or Wildfly configuration?**

Comment: Loading two classes with the same qualified name is just gambling.

Comment: You should use jboss-deployment-structure.xml to define your dependencies and exclude the classes you want to override